# Receiving error when passing Base64 png info as query sting in URL

Tags: javascript, base64

Attempting to pass Base64 image data in Url to web page on same domain. Query string works correctly for text strings, but receiving error -VM8:2759 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated - when attaching the base64 data.

```
var url = "somepage.html?name=" + encodeURIComponent("sometext") + "&image=" + base64Data;
```

Base64 data was initially fetched from a php script, and being forwarded from one webpage to another - same domain.  Image file does not exist on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Using gigantic query strings can be problematic, because different browsers have different rules, and in your case, the base64 blob image string could be compromised by URL encoding etc.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/812962/1772933

It's really best practice to use `POST` to send this quantity of data.

Comment: Image was of QR code.  It is far under the limitations for query string size limitation set by browsers, even for older IE browser.